# How to update provider value on a future builder in Flutter using Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I am trying to implement an auto-login feature. Basically on the startup, I want to check if any user data is saved at Flutter Secure Storage and then update my userProvider based on the result.

Here is the build method of the first screen

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: checkUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if(snapshot.hasData){
          print("has data");
          ref.read(userProvider.notifier).setUser(
            snapshot.data!
          );
        }
        else if(snapshot.hasError){
          print(snapshot.error);
        }
        else{
          
          return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
            ),
          );
        }

        return AppBody(context);
      },
    );
  }
```

And here is the provider I am trying to update

```
final userProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, User?>((ref) {
  return UserNotifier();
});
```

It gives me this error:

Tried to modify a provider while the widget tree was building.
If you are encountering this error, chances are you tried to
modify a provider
in a widget life-cycle, such as but not limited to:

- build
- initState
- dispose
- didUpdateWidget
- didChangeDepedencies

Where can i update the provider value if I can not do it on the initializing?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: build() should be idempotent, and not try to update anything of any dependent state.  Think of it this way... once you start building, you're building from a snapshot of all external data exactly as-is. The build() method wants to paint a screen "as-is".  If you try to alter that during the build, as you did, then the framework rightfully complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a `FutureProvider` to load the cached user data and consume the provider in the widget's `build` method.

```dart
final userProvider = FutureProvider<User?>((ref) async {
  final user = await ... // load user data from flutter secure storage
  return user;
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final AsyncValue<User?> userAsync = ref.watch(userProvider);
  return userAsync.when(
    data: (user) {
      if (user == null) {
        return // login page;
      } else {
        return // home page;
      }
    },
    loading: () => const Text('loading'),
    error: (error, stack) => const Text('error'),
  );
}
```

if you want to keep track of the user state, you could define a `isLoggedInProvider`.

```dart
final isLoggedInProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(userProvider).asData?.value;
  return user != null;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but this solution is for initializing stage only, right? Because I also would like to use this userProvider in other parts of the app, for example a button will only be clickable or an action will only be performed if user is logged in. Do I have to await everytime for this provider to get that async value from secure storage? Thanks again..

Comment: I will probably define a `isLoggedInProvider`.

final isLoggedInProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(userProvider).asData?.value;
  return user != null;
});